# What is the name for the pieces of metal in a rack that cage nuts are installed into?

Tags: rack

You would not believe how much consternation this simple question has caused my office. :)

When installing cage nuts to mount rails or equipment, the nuts are clipped into a piece of metal with square holes, usually labeled with the rack unit number:

[image: A rack with the part being asked about highlighted]

... as highlighted in red.

How does one refer to this part of a rack?

Comment: I'd call that the "post".

Comment: The only place I'd be putting a cage nut, is the cage. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mounting Flange.  It's defined in "EIA-310-D, Cabinets, Racks, Panels, and Associated Equipment".  It may not be easy to find a legitimately free (the EIA charges for it) copy online, but you can find plenty of references to it.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard a specific name for only that exact part of the rack.

Like @joeqwerty said, usually it's just called the post.  A standard server rack is called a "4-post rack", and there are "2-post racks" which were (are?) common in telco use when the gear to be mounted is a bit lighter in weight.

However, that really refers to the whole piece of metal, not just the part which the cage nuts attach to.  So @luke-peterson's suggestion of "cage" is probably the closest thing to just the part you're trying to name.

Comment: Calling it the "post" seems fine to me.